# PHP Calendar - SELECT rows from MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

Im using this PHP code to display a calendar.

```
<?php
$monthNames = Array("January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", 
"August", "September", "October", "November", "December");
?>

<?php
if (!isset($_REQUEST["month"])) $_REQUEST["month"] = date("n");
if (!isset($_REQUEST["year"])) $_REQUEST["year"] = date("Y");
?>

<?php
$cMonth = $_REQUEST["month"];
$cYear = $_REQUEST["year"];

$prev_year = $cYear;
$next_year = $cYear;
$prev_month = $cMonth-1;
$next_month = $cMonth+1;

if ($prev_month == 0 ) {
    $prev_month = 12;
    $prev_year = $cYear - 1;
}
if ($next_month == 13 ) {
    $next_month = 1;
    $next_year = $cYear + 1;
}
?>

<table width="100%">
<tr align="center">
    <td bgcolor="#999999" style="color:#FFFFFF"><table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
        <tr>
            <td width="50%" align="left">  <a href="<?php echo $_SERVER["PHP_SELF"] . "?month=". $prev_month . "&year=" . $prev_year; ?>" style="color:#FFFFFF">Previous</a></td>
            <td width="50%" align="right"><a href="<?php echo $_SERVER["PHP_SELF"] . "?month=". $next_month . "&year=" . $next_year; ?>" style="color:#FFFFFF">Next</a>  </td>
        </tr>
    </table></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td align="center"><table width="100%" border="1" cellpadding="2" cellspacing="2">
        <tr align="center">
            <td colspan="7" bgcolor="#999999" style="color:#FFFFFF"><strong><?php echo $monthNames[$cMonth-1].' '.$cYear; ?></strong></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td align="center" bgcolor="#999999" style="color:#FFFFFF"><strong>S</strong></td>
            <td align="center" bgcolor="#999999" style="color:#FFFFFF"><strong>M</strong></td>
            <td align="center" bgcolor="#999999" style="color:#FFFFFF"><strong>T</strong></td>
            <td align="center" bgcolor="#999999" style="color:#FFFFFF"><strong>W</strong></td>
            <td align="center" bgcolor="#999999" style="color:#FFFFFF"><strong>T</strong></td>
            <td align="center" bgcolor="#999999" style="color:#FFFFFF"><strong>F</strong></td>
            <td align="center" bgcolor="#999999" style="color:#FFFFFF"><strong>S</strong></td>
        </tr>
        <?php 
        $timestamp = mktime(0,0,0,$cMonth,1,$cYear);
        $maxday = date("t",$timestamp);
        $thismonth = getdate ($timestamp);
        $startday = $thismonth['wday'];
        for ($i=0; $i<($maxday+$startday); $i++)
        {
            $sql="SELECT * from calendar where date = '".$cYear."-".$cMonth."-".($i - $startday + 1)."' ";
            $rs=mysql_query($sql,$conn) or die(mysql_error());
            $result=mysql_fetch_array($rs);

            if(($i % 7) == 0 )
            {
                echo '<tr>';
            }
            if($i < $startday)
            {
                echo '<td></td>';
            }
            else
            {
                echo '<td align="center" valign="middle" height="80px" width="80px"><a href="add.php?date='.($i - $startday + 1).'-'.$cMonth.'-'.$cYear.'">'. ($i - $startday + 1) . '</a><br>'.$result["title"].'</td>';
            }
            if(($i % 7) == 6 )
            {
                echo '</tr>';
            }
        }
        ?></table></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

it works perfectly, however i have added a select sql query near the bottom which will show rows from a table in MySQL for that certain date, however i cannot work out how to make it show all rows with that date. i have tried using this as a while loop but no luck. any ideas how i can make it show all rows for each date if there are multiple rows?

Comment: what you mean by this `$i - $startday + 1` ? did tried to echo it and see what it gives ?

Comment: You should NOT be using the deprecated mysql_* functions, you should be using mysqli_*. You should NEVER include un-escaped variables in a SQL query like that, anyone can come along and inject SQL here and abuse your database. See ```mysqli_real_escape_string```.

Comment: @echo_Samir this echos each day in the calendar

Comment: Also you should check its an interger on your input validation plus fix the XSS hole by using `$_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]`

Answer (score 1):

you should use GROUP BY in your query

```
$sql="SELECT * from calendar where date = '".$cYear."-".$cMonth."-".($i - $startday + 1)."' GROUP BY the_column_that_you_sort_your_table ";
```

Comment: yes group by days columns if you have , can you show your table ?